# NodeJS HTTP response.redirect dosen't exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to do a little test and redirect to google instantly but it says that response.redirect dosen't exist

Here's my code:

```
function Server(req, res) {
    res.redirect('http://www.google.com');
    res.end();
}

var server = http.createServer(Server);

server.listen(8080);
console.log('Server is running...');
```

The error im getting:

> TypeError: res.redirect is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such method on `http.ServerResponse` (see [the manual](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse)).

You've most likely read documentation from the [express](http://expressjs.com/) project, a popular web server framework, which has a `redirect` method on the response object.

Write the appropriate headers manually instead

```
response.writeHead(302, {
  'Location': 'your/path.html'
});
```

Comment: Basically all the 3xx status codes represent redirections, signaling the reason for the redirect. The location header alone is usually enough to make a user agent do the right thing but the status code should be set too. So, yes it matters for semantics.